# Превратить символы "+" "-" в операторы + -

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Дано:**

- случайное количество чисел от 2 до 4;
- значение чисел так же случайное от 10 до 99;
- между числами случайные операторы "+" или "-"

**Требуется вывести результат:**

- А1 +/- А2 +/- А3 +/- А4

Код:

```
import random

b = []
n = random.randint(2, 4)

for i in range(n):
    b.append(random.randint(10, 99))
    b.append(random.choice(['+', '-']))

print(''.join(map(str, b[:-1])))
```

Выводится красиво, только не вычисляет:
`85-67+43+11`

Comment: Для расширения кругозора: операторы языка доступны в виде функций в модуле **operator**:

    from operator import add, sub
    ops = {add: '+', sub: '-'}  # Сопоставим символам.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте функцию [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). Хоть она и небезопасна, т.к. может выполнить любой код, но раз ее код формируете вы, то проблем не вижу:

```
import random

b = []
n = random.randint(2, 4)

for i in range(n):
    b.append(random.randint(10, 99))
    b.append(random.choice(['+', '-']))

calc_text = ''.join(map(str, b[:-1]))
print('{} = {}'.format(calc_text, eval(calc_text)))
# 29-93-21 = -85
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть много видов калькуляторов, часто делают через польскую запись.

Вот мой пример с рекурсией:

```
import random

b = []
n = random.randint(2, 4)

for i in range(n):
    b.append(random.randint(10, 99))
    b.append(random.choice(['+', '-']))

s = ''.join(map(str, b[:-1]))


def resum(s):
    if '-' in s:
        a,b = s.split('-', maxsplit=1)
        return resum(a) - resum(b)
    elif '+' in s:
        a,b = s.split('+', maxsplit=1)
        return resum(a) + resum(b)
    else:
        return int(s)

print(s+'='+str(resum(s)))
```